# How to query files using FileManager in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, file, nsfilemanager

I just got started with `FileManager` and wanted to know if there was a way to query files against custom attributes without having to retrieve the contents of the files.

Similar to `creationDate` or `modificationDate`, I want to have an attribute called `topicsCovered` which is an array of strings containing things such as "technology", "politics", etc. (for news articles). Since News Articles may have many images, I don't want to unnecessarily retrieve ALL the news articles, convert them into concrete types, and then filter out the ones I don't want (specially since I'll be storing a maximum of 500 articles, which would mean retrieving ~1gb worth of files from disk).

So if there is a way to query files before retrieving them using `FileManager` please let me know since I feel retrieving ~1gb worth of files from disk may be a very expensive/heavy operation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just create a custom structure and store your file url with whatever you need.

Comment: @LeoDabus What do you mean by "store your file url with whatever you need"? Sorry I just got started with file manager so I'm not too sure how to do that or what that means

Comment: I mean FileManager has no special powers. If you know already what a file contains just store that info along with its url. Otherwise you will need to load each file contents at least once.

Comment: @LeoDabus Alright, I'll look into this. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you want to keep it on memory you might need to use a [cache](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscache). Otherwise just store your structured data in your application directory. Light weight data access from disk should be pretty fast.

Comment: @LeoDabus Hey Leo sorry for coming back to this so late. I never really understood what you meant by "store that info along with its url". Did you mean storing a `.txt` file in the Cache folder which contains all the topics and the UUID's of articles which cover those topics? Or did you mean something different?

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of files in your system. I suggest that you create an extra file, "metadata", that contains the metadata about all the other files (for e.g. the topics covered information), and the URL/filenames to the files themselves. You could also store this metadata in CoreData or some database table.

Then when you are looking for all the "politics" articles for example, you open the metadata file and find all the entries that cover politics which will give you the filenames of the files you want to load.

Comment: Could I store this information in the urls themselves like @Leo suggested in the comments? *"If you know already what a file contains just store that info along with its url."*

Comment: "Store that info along with the URL" is exactly what I'm suggesting you do. You have to store that info somewhere though so it's either in a different file or it's in a database.

Comment: Hey Daniel, sorry for coming back to this so late. I just wanted to clarify something because I think I've misunderstood it. By "store that info along with the URL" do you mean saving all the `Article`s in a folder called "Articles Cache" and in that folder have a `.txt` file which has all the possible topics and an array of UUID's which match those topics? Then I can just query the `.txt` file for a topic and instantly get all the UUID's that I need. After that, I finally use `FileManager` to retrieve the files using ".../Articles Cache/<UUID>". Or did you mean something completely different?

Comment: Sure, that's a solution.